# WPF DockPanel Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change the alignment of my dockPanel, and I'm having some trouble. I'm relatively new to WPF, so that may explain it.

Anyways, here is the current layout:

```
    <theme:bottomPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="bottomPanel" ClipToBounds="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="145" />
    <theme:rightPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="rightPanel" ClipToBounds="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="False"/>
    <theme:leftPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="leftPanel" ClipToBounds="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" />
    <theme:MapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="mapPanel" ClipToBounds="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" />
```

Visualized in Paint (lol) :

[image]

I would like to change the layout to something like the following:

[image]

Is this possible? If so, what approach would you recommend? Any guidance would be helpful! Thank you.

As an aside: is there any application that allows me to see my application layout as the app runs (i.e. add gridlines to each panel or something)?

Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to stick to DockPanels or would a couple Grids suffice?

Comment: is the content going to grow? (i.e. the colored blocks?) or is it going to be a fixed size at all times?

Comment: Fixed size at all times. And I'm open to any solution - dockPanels are not a necessity.

Comment: Why don't you use something like https://avalondock.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: It's easy to do with a `Grid` but I'd have to ask how the content of the 'old top' is expected to behave? Like does everything in gray just float behind the other stuff, or does that top right corner act as its own cell, etc.

Comment: It all acts as one. So the little right corner is still part of that area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Background="Gray" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <TextBlock Text="Top Area"/>
    </Border>

    <Border Background="Magenta" Grid.Row="1" Height="200">
        <TextBlock Text="Left Area"/>
    </Border>

    <Border Background="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="200">
        <TextBlock Text="Bottom Area"/>
    </Border>

    <Border Background="Cyan" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,200,0,0" Width="200">
        <TextBlock Text="Right Area"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: I'm getting tired to see you posting duplicated questions...]

Comment: Many thanks. Sorry if you thought I was duplicating questions - had no intention of doing so. Thanks for helping the noobie out :)